# Pushing a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem with pushing a viewcontroller. This is what I did: on the click of a button I add a modal view using this code I it works fine:

```
- (void)addAction:(id)sender
{
    uipickerForContract *addViewController = [[uipickerForContract alloc] initWithNibName:@"uipickerForContract" bundle:nil];
    addViewController.delegate = self;

    addViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    addViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:addViewController animated:YES];

    addViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 740, 695, 245);


}
```

this added viewcontroller contains a done button , that I want to use in order to navigate to other viewcontroller : so I use that code  but it didn't work , it just dismiss the addeview :

```
 donebutton{

    nextview*s = [[nextview alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextview" bundle:nil];
    s.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 745, 755);
    //nextview contains the object that I want to pass :object
        s.object= self;
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:s animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"self.nav%@",self.navigationController);
     }
```

Comment: once you call [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; control goes back push View will not be called. Check whether nslog self.nav%@ is printing

Comment: Yes , nslog self.nav%@ is printing

Comment: this line `UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];
` is useless instatiation. Could you be more precise : both your code samples belong to the same class (viewController), or does 'self' represent different things here?

Comment: Than you for reply , the addAction belongs to  viewcontroller that reciev the addedviewcontroller .inside this addedviewcontroller , I use navigationcontroller in order to push this view to otherviewcontroller

Comment: So the `doneButton` method belongs to the same class as `addAction`?

Comment: No addAction belongs to one viewController , then done belongs to another, which is added to the first one

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController of view controller (you presented modally) will be nil

and you are not able to notice this thing because you are allocating navigation controller object.

Comment: get the reference of navigation controller object from previous view controller and use that to again push view controller.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put some delay between dismiss and next push something like this

**Before :**

```
nextview*s = [[nextview alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextview" bundle:nil];
s.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 745, 755);
//nextview contains the object that I want to pass :object
    s.object= self;
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:s animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"self.nav%@",self.navigationController);
```

**After :**

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(pushNextView) withObject:nil afterDelaye:0.40];

- (void) pushNextView {
    nextview*s = [[nextview alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextview" bundle:nil];
    s.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 745, 755);
    //nextview contains the object that I want to pass :object
        s.object= self;
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:s animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"self.nav%@",self.navigationController);
}
```

Comment: I disagree, I have UINavigationController pushing viewController after an action in a modal controller, and NO delay is needed between `[self dismissViewController animated...]` and `[self.navigationController pushViewController:...]`

Comment: [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];
        nextview*s = [[nextview alloc] initWithNibName: @"nextview" 
                                                bundle: nil];
        s.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 745, 755);
        s.object= self;
       [self.navigationController pushViewController: s 
                                            animated: YES];
    });